# React Router V4, Not matching anything under first parent in Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building an app that has 2 parent layouts (Public.js and Main.js) and they are in a Router (BrowserRouter) and a Switch. I can match all the Public routes just fine but anything under the Public doesn't match and the Public template remains.

I tried it a couple ways with the same result:

V1 Routes:

```
...
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Public>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
        </Public>
        <Main>
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path='/file/records' component={Records} />
        </Main>
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
...
```

V1: Public.js

```
...
<div className="container-fluid">
{ this.props.children }
</div>
...
```

V1: Main.js

```
...
<main className="bmd-layout-content">
<div className="container-fluid p-0">
{ this.props.children }
</div>
</main>
...
```

V2 Routes:

```
 ...
    <Router>
    <Switch>
    <Public />
    <Main />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
    </Router>
    ...
```

V2 Public:

```
...
<div className="container-fluid">
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
<Route path='/login' component={Login} />
<Route path='/register' component={Register} />
</div>
...
```

V2 Main:

```
...
<main className="bmd-layout-content">
<div className="container-fluid p-0">
<Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
<Route path='/file/records' component={Records} />
</div>
</main>
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is including the base template in the route's render call:

```
<Route path='/dashboard' render={() => <Main><Dashboard /></Main>} />
```